# How to select all data with inner join

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

How to select data from 2 table with inner join 
but i want to show all like below. how to do it?

```
select h1, h2 
from table_1 t1 inner join table_2 t2
     on t1.h1 = t2.h1
```

table_1

```
h1  |    h2   |
one    thai
two    malasia
three  japan
```

table_2

```
h1    |    h2    |
one       fish
two       dog
```

after execute command i want to show like this

```
h1     |     h2     |
one         fish
two         dog
three      <null>
```

Comment: You need to include the correct table aliases like `select t1.h1, t2.h2....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner join can't show null values. Try left join:

```
select A.h1, B.h2
from table_1 A
left join table_2 B ON A.h1 = B.h1
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join doesn't match nulls. I suggest you read about differences between inner join and outer join (in your case t1 on the left has all the rows so you want a left outer join, or simply left join).